# UpdatePanel doesn't work if validator error

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, validation

When there is an error with CompareValidators, the triggers for the UpdatePanel stop working. I didn't find any info about that..

Comment: i found that putting the same validationGroup for all validators allow the updatePanel to work even if there are error..

Answer (score 0):

If you set [EnableClientScript="false"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) on the CompareValidators, the error wont block the post-back and the update panel will work.

> Client-side validation enhances the validation process by checking user input before it is sent to the server. This allows errors to be detected on the client before the form is submitted, avoiding the round trip of information necessary for server-side validation.

Comment: well thanks for the idea,
but i found that putting the same validationGroup for all validators allow the updatePanel to work even if there are error..

Comment: Validation group does something else. If you don't set the validationGroup on the controls that postback, there is not client side validation because there is not validators on the control's validation group; so you achieve the same in a less efficient way. There is also the [CauseValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx) property that you could set to false on the control that you want to post-back even if there's an error.